# Sql Server Audit

Tags: sql-server

How can I find Stored procedure parameters from fn_get_audit_file?

Server:SQL 2016 SP1

I use Audit/Database Audit Specification.
I am monitoring one table with this solution (update,insert,delete) but I cannot find the SPs parameters  in additional_information or statement.

Is there any chance to "decrypt" this data from this log?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. `fn_get_audit_file` is a function, not a procedure. It has the following three parameters: `@file_pattern`, `@initial_file_name`, and `@audit_record_offset`. You can see this by executing `EXEC helptext 'fn_get_audit_file'` or checking he documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-get-audit-file-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I created a DatabaseAuditSpecification on a table and I read the files with this query:

SELECT * FROM fn_get_audit_file('L:\Queries\*', default, default)

But i cannot find the parameters of the stored procedure if the table was updated, inserted by a Stored Procedure